# quiero pasar una cadena a lista y de lista a string

Tags: python

Por ejemplo, tengo

```
["Hola","buenos","dias"]
```

Y lo necesito pasar a:

```
Hola
buenas
dias
```

Y por ultimo pasar eso a string, aunque creo con con "json.dumps" se puede hacer ese cambio no?.

Comment: ¿Y qué has intentado? Te invito a leer [ask] y a realizar el [tour]. La entrada es una lista que contiene "Hola", "buenos", "dias", pero la salida dice: *Hola buenas tardes*. Por otro lado, en Python puedes usar [`str.join(iterable)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join). Saludos

Answer (score -9, accepted):

Cuando tenes una lista se acomodan en índices

```
["Hola","buenos","dias"]

0       1       2
```

Si utilizas los corchetes y elegís el índice obtener el valor o usando el método get

```
list[0] === "HOLA"

list.get(0) === "HOLA"
```

Comment: Esta respuesta es incorrecta a muchos niveles. Primero parece que el código mostrado no es Python (es quizás javascript?). Python no tiene el operador `===` , para comparar se usa `==`. Segundo Python no tiene el método `.get()` para listas y un intento de usarlo daría una excepción. Tercero no se responde a nada de lo que el OP pregunta (ni como se convierte una cadena en lista ni cómo una lista en cadena, ni cómo modificar uno de sus elementos). **Sin embargo el OP la ha aceptado**... No entiendo nada.

Comment: === IDENTICO list[0] es === "HOLA" por que retorna una string.

Comment: Matias. Borre todos tus comentarios. La idea de esta pagina es ayudar con codigo correcto y que funcione. Tus modales en este caso, no fueron para nada correctos. Un usuario, te dejo un monton de dudas sobre lo que pusiste en tu respuesta, y solo te dedicaste a atacarlo, en lugar de explicar porque tu respuesta es correcta, o marcarle a dicho usuario si estaba equivocado.

Answer (score 5):

Dado que lo que pones como ejemplo *aparentemente ya es una lista*, y por tanto la pregunta no tendría sentido, voy a suponer que lo que en realidad tienes es una cadena cuyo contenido tiene aspecto de lista. Así:

```
cadena = '["Hola","buenos","dias"]'
```

### Conversión a lista

En ese caso necesitas que Python interprete esa cadena como si fuera un dato, para poder guardar el resultado en una variable de tipo lista.

Una forma muy simple es usar `eval`:

```
lista = eval(cadena)
```

No obstante puede ser peligroso si no tienes control sobre lo que contendrá realmente `cadena`, ya que si contuviera sentencias Python, éstas serían ejecutadas y no sabes lo que podrían hacer. Para evitar ese problema puedes usar `ast.literal_eval()`:

```
import ast
lista = ast.literal_eval(cadena)
```

Esto funcionará si lo que contiene `cadena` es un **dato literal** válido (incluso si es una lista) y fallará si contiene otras cosas como comandos u operaciones.

Finalmente también podrías usar el módulo `json`, que para este caso particular podría funcionar gracias a que lo que contiene la lista son cadenas delimitadas por comillas dobles, tal como JSON espera:

```
import json
lista = json.loads(cadena)
```

### Modificación de la lista

De cualquiera de las tres formas llegas al mismo resultado:

```
print(lista)
---
['Hola', 'buenos', 'dias']
```

Ahora ya puedes acceder al elemento de la lista que desees y cambiarlo por otra cosa.  Para acceder al elemento `"dias"`, ya que es el tercero, podrías usar `lista[2]` (se numeran desde 0). O también, ya que es el último, podrías usar `lista[-1]` (los subíndices negativos se cuentan desde el final).

```
lista[-1] = "tardes"
```

### Conversión de nuevo a cadena

Entiendo que lo que buscas es que el resultado tenga de nuevo aspecto de lista, como tenía la cadena original, y no que se concatenen las palabras para formar una frase. Si lo que buscabas era la concatenación podrías hacerlo así:

```
frase = " ".join(lista)
```

que produciría el resultado `"Hola buenas tardes"`.

Si lo que quieres es que tenga aspecto de lista, una forma muy directa es usar `str()`:

```
cadena = str(lista)
print(cadena)
----
['Hola', 'buenos', 'tardes']
```

Sin embargo observa que para representar las cadenas dentro de la lista Python ha elegido el delimitador `'` en vez de `"`. Esto te causará problemas si luego intentas leerlo como JSON porque el JSON requiere `"` como delimitador de cadenas (no te causaría problemas en cambio si lo lees con `eval()` o con `ast.literal_eval()`, ya que éstas esperan sintaxis Python y en esa sintaxis las comillas simples o dobles son lo mismo).

Si quieres que el resultado sea volcado con comillas dobles puedes usar `json.dumps()`:

```
cadena = json.dumps(lista)
print(cadena)
---
["Hola", "buenos", "tardes"]
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, enserio fue de mucha ayuda, :333 graciaaaas

Comment: De nada, pero...¿podrías aclarar, ya sólo por curiosidad, qué estabas preguntando en realidad? Yo creía que había respondido a tu pregunta, pero veo que la respuesta aceptada está respondiendo a otra cosa completamente diferente. ¿Al final tu problema era sólo cómo usar los índices para acceder a elementos de una lista?

Answer (score 0):

```
a = ["Hola","buenos","dias"]

for i in a:
    print(i) # Esto te retornará el resultado que esperas.. 
    print(type(i)) # return =>  <class 'str'>
```

Eso te devuelve el resultado que esperas no?

Comment: Perfecto, muchas gracias :3